# How to keep two objects in the same zone when they collide?

Tags: unity

I made a zone out of a cylinder with zero height. When one sphere moves to that zone it is fine but if another one moves to the same zone it only shows one sphere.

I tried to add a rigid body for each sphere but they collide inside the cylinder and both fly. I want both of them to collide but stay inside the cylinder zone with a distance between them like 2 units.

Comment: Have you tried using a collider for the zone ? but I am not particularly sure it's clear what you are asking. Images would help.

Comment: Yes, images or diagrams would be really helpful here. Your problem is very unclear.

Comment: I know the answer but cannot answer because someone didn't understand you and put your question on hold :P You have to not use the rigid body physics, use the collider as a trigger, write a script to stop and put the spheres where you want when the collider is activated.

Comment: @Roberto Feel free to provide your answer.

Comment: @Roberto Based on my understanding he can still use rigid-bodies. The problem he is having is, once both shapes have entered his zone, they fly out. He can keep the rigid-bodies but he needs to detect when both entity's have entered zone and create a collider around the zone to prevent them from leaving it.

Comment: @Grey Yes, I think you are right, Grey, that's probably better for him since he probably wants to keep using the rigid bodies to simulate physics in the rest of his application.

Comment: Why are you creating a zone with zero height, and trying to keep 3D objects inside that? Containing a 3D object inside a (essentially) 2D object doesn't make sense.